# Paper recommendations for career guidance

Tags: cosmology, stellar-astrophysics, resource-request

I'm an undergraduate student in astronomy and I'm one year from graduating, but I feel I still can't choose what career path I want to pursue. To date I've only had two courses of proper astrophysics and I liked them both. I have a notion of cosmology (CMB, B modes) and basic stellar astrophysics but I would like to explore more fields of research. Maybe this is too much to ask but it would really be of help a list of papers that describe, in general of course, different fields. It's something like this I want to read https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9512285. If you know more papers like this please share them, they could be about exoplanets, star populations, mergers, AGNs, astrochemistry, weird stars, anything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you have access through the paywall but [Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics](https://www.annualreviews.org/journal/astro) produces very good surveys of a particular field. Another (free) source could be the ongoing Astro2020 Decadal Survey. The Science & State of the Profession White Papers provide a good, short summary of what the community thinks the important issues are for the next decade. Paper Links from [here](https://www.nationalacademies.org/our-work/decadal-survey-on-astronomy-and-astrophysics-2020-astro2020#sl-three-columns-f5774dd4-4354-4df3-8fe0-55647a727271)

Comment: cool, thank you!!!

Comment: Space Science Reviews (https://www.springer.com/journal/11214) is another reasonable place to look.  But I'm not sure reading papers is the best thing to do if you're trying to figure out whether you like astronomy and, if so, more specifically what area of astronomy.  Almost every academic department should have a seminar or colloquia series where they bring people in to talk about their work in the field.  A good professor in the department should also be able to talk with you about various options and recommend resources.